# I can't get haskell-tools working in LazyVim

Tags: neovim, lazyvim

I'am trying set up my LazyVim and i would like to have *haskell-tools* working.

I can't figure out, where start looking for problem, in my ubuntu system i got several version of GHC, HLS installed via GHCup. Config of plugin is below.

Problem is i don't have clue what is wrong beside note (from nvim) `"Client <x> quite with exit code 1 and signal 0."` I didn't find that useful, I don't know what that actually means. Except this clue i can't see any command of `haskell-tool.nvim` in nvim's cmd. `:checkhealth haskell-tools` and `:LspInfo` seems heatlhy.

Can someone point me to what check or try?

This is my config of haskell-tools:

```
-- haskell-tools.lua
return {
    "mrcjkb/haskell-tools.nvim",
    dependencies = {
        "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
        "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim",
    },
    version = "^3", -- Recommended
    -- branch = "2.x.x", -- Recommended
    config = function() -- Optional, see Advanced configuration
        vim.g.haskell_tools = {}
    end,
    -- load the plugin when opening one of the following file types
    ft = { "haskell", "lhaskell", "cabal", "cabalproject" },
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim. Could you tell us where exactly (in which file and where on the disk) did you put the configuration you refer to in your question (where is `haskell-tools.lua` and how did you referenced it in your general configuration)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I am following [lazyvi documentation](https://www.lazyvim.org/configuration). I put  `haskell-tools.lua` inside `~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins` folder. From this folder are my all plugins, i am using, loaded.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to have [haskell-tools](https://github.com/mrcjkb/haskell-tools.nvim) running on my [LazyVim](https://www.lazyvim.org/) system:

- Install [ghc](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/install/)
- Install the [Haskell Language Server](https://haskell-language-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)
- Add the following `haskell-tools.lua` in: `~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins` folder

```lua
return {
    {
        'mrcjkb/haskell-tools.nvim',
        version = '^3', -- Recommended
        ft = { 'haskell', 'lhaskell', 'cabal', 'cabalproject' },
    }
}
```

- Add the following `haskell-tool.lua` in `~/.config/nvim/lua/config` folder

```lua
-- haskell-tools.lua
return {
    "mrcjkb/haskell-tools.nvim",
    dependencies = {
        "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
        "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim",
    },
    version = "^3", -- Recommended
    -- branch = "2.x.x", -- Recommended
    config = function() -- Optional, see Advanced configuration
        vim.g.haskell_tools = {}
    end,
    -- load the plugin when opening one of the following file types
    ft = { "haskell", "lhaskell", "cabal", "cabalproject" },
}
```

- Restart LazyVim